# Is there a hook that fires when a row of wp_sitemeta table is updated?

Tags: hooks

I'm looking for something like the `updated_options` hook but instead of firing when a row from wp_options is updated, I want to perform some action when a row from `wp_sitemeta` is updated. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I see you asked this earlier today then deleted it and re-asked. If you need to adjust your question you can use the `edit` button, otherwise deleting and reposting the same question will get your account flagged by the anti-spam systems. You also lost an upvote by deleting and reposting